# DDD Sample : CargoRepository.Store() could be used in a controller?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, encapsulation

I'm looking at the great NDDDSample source from http://code.google.com/p/ndddsample to learn about DDD. Am confused with something

The CargoRepository has a Find() method which is called by BookingService.AssignCargoToRoute() and CargoTrackingController.Search() :

```
Cargo cargo = CargoRepository.Find(trackingId);
```

CargoRepository also has a Store() method called from BookingService.AssignCargoToRoute() :

```
Cargo cargo = cargoRepository.Find(trackingId);
if (cargo == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Can't assign itinerary to non-existing cargo " + trackingId);
}

cargo.AssignToRoute(itinerary);
cargoRepository.Store(cargo);
```

My confusion is that there seems to be nothing to stop the CargoTrackingController from calling CargoRepository.Store() which would bypass the business logic in the BookingService.AssignCargoToRoute()

Why is this allowed in DDD? Should the repository be split into two, one for read for the application/ui/domain/service and one for write for the domain/services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DDD, Services are not the holders of all business logic. They only represent verbs, actions of the domain that are cross-concern to several objects and thus wouldn't fit into one of the entities or aggregate roots without breaking single responsibility principle and creating tight couplings that would muddle the entity.

In your example, Cargo.AssignToRoute(itinerary) and BookingService.AssignCargoToRoute() seem to be redundant. The existence of these 2 ways to bind a cargo to a route creates confusion. You could keep either of them, depending on whether you think it is the responsibility of the Cargo to assign itself a route, or that it overloads the entity with functionality that doesn't belong in it.

Other than that, it is perfectly legitimate for a Controller to call a Repository method directly. Services are not the single point of access for Controllers.

Comment: I have been looking at domain objects in the wrong way it seems. I had thought I'd call oEntity.Load( someId) then oEntity.DoSomething( x) and then oEntity.Save(), but that's putting the responsibility of persistence in the entity which violates single responsibility principle badly. The entity should only have methods that act on itself and services are created where multiple entities are involved in a single business process. I am getting more of an understanding now thanks. Interesting stuff this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess that's what CQRS is trying to achieve.

Of course in this case bypassing BL is a bad idea (and apparently quite easy to achieve, which is even worse). But you just cant't enforce all the rules in code, some will just stay conventions not explicitly declared in the code. Some bad things may be hard, but still not impossible to achieve, and there are always lots of silly mistakes one can make. That's just what programming is: you have to think what you're really doing, or else no guidelines, like DDD, will help you pull it off.

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading too much into DDD and just need to trust common sense as well as adopt the guidelines. So here I would split the repository interface into two (ICargoRepositoryRead and ICargoRepositoryUpdate) and give the Controller access to the ICargoRepositoryRead interface

Answer (score 1):

The separation of application  in persistence lair and service lair is needed to help you as a developer to maintain some structure that is easy to understand and maintain, it's developers responsibility to follow some pattern and use code properly.

It's not framework which restricts you (developer) from using it's incorrectly, DDD is design pattern (a guidance how to organize you application structure).

Comment: Thanks, I understand now that DDD is just a framework for design. So in this case I would have to assume that the client code in the controller wants to cause as much damage as possible, so I would never give it a repository with update capabilities even though this DDD sample does

Comment: @Gareth: The service lair is used internally, for external service consumed by clients you create Web Service (for example using WCF in .NET) which is usually based on your Service lair, and there you define what methods of your Service lair are exposed to clients, and control the permissions (authorization).